# JQuery posting form via AJAX not triggering rails respond_to format.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple form with an order by param. When my dropdown is changed, I call this:

```
$.post("/busca", $("#order_form").serialize(), dataType: "script")
```

On the rails controller side I have a simple `format.js` to handle the ajax calls.
Thing is that this isn't working. The `js.erb` template is never rendered.

My log shows `Processing by BuscaController#index as */*` and I have no idea what the `*/*` stands for. Can someone help me?

Comment: It looks like you didn't specify the format in the request

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. When you have a respond_to block like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

It will not work. You need to setup the js response first than the HTML one. Don't ask me why.
This is the one that works for me:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html
end
```

Comment: Check the Accept headers being sent by the browser. If the Accept header has "*/*" (i.e any format is Ok), then the first format block in respond_to will trigger. If you want to ensure the the .js block is invoked, then one way is to ensure the Accept header has 'text/javascript'. You can set accept headers when sending any ajax request via jQuery or any framework.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that all post parameters are mandatory:

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )
```

I was able to get the js when doing this:

```
$.post("/busca", $("#order_form").serialize(), function() { }, "script")
```

No matter the `format.x` order

Comment: still doesn't explain why it works without the mandatory callback, when you have the format.js first