# Rails ajax request not setting the proper request type?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am having a few issues:

- The request is coming in as an <strike>html</strike>(see edit below, its coming in as "*/*" in the log) request, so the format.js is never hit. From what I assumed, ajax requests should be coming in as a js request. Is there something I am not doing properly? Do I need to specify the type of the request? In order to do that, would I set the dataType parameter in the ajax call?
- It was actually working at some point, the request came in as js and the controller responded with a 200, but for some reason the success function was never triggered, so the new partial was never rendered.

Here is my js for watching click events on a page to render a partial:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".profile-section-tab").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    newTab = $(this);
    user_id = window.location.pathname.split("/")[2]
    newTabRoute = "/member/" + user_id + "/" + newTab.data("profileSection")
    if (!newTab.hasClass("active-tab")) {
      $.ajax({url: newTabRoute, type: "GET", success: function(data) {
          $(".profile-section-tab").removeClass("active-tab");
          newTab.addClass("active-tab");
          $("#profile-section-content").html(data);
        }});
     };
  });
});
```

And here is the controller code:

```
def some_profile_section
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render partial: "/members/sections/some_profile_section" }
  end
end
```

EDIT: So I read in another question that commented code might cause issues, so removing some comments has changed things. The request coming in is now looking like:

```
Processing by MembersController#account_settings as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"editor"}
```

Also, I am calling `request.xhr?` in the controller method before the respond to, and it is returning `0` instead of `true`.

EDIT 2: Per infused's help below, I am now getting the js to come in as a js request, and the partial is called. Where I am at now is that request.xhr? is still not returning true but 0, which I am not sure how relevant that is but I am assuming it should be true, and the success function in my jquery is not triggered, so the partial is not getting placed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Set `dataType: 'script'` in your Ajax request. Then Rails will respond with the `.js` template.

Comment: I haven't seen anywhere in blog posts or so qa's that the dataType is set in an ajax request for a controller to properly respond. Is that something I have to do because of some non-default I way I am doing this? Also, take a look at my edit, would love your thoughts. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You didn't look very hard then as there are lots of references to it.  Here's the top two from my recent search:  http://whoneedsactions.com/blog/2010/10/24/jquery-ajax-with-rails-respond-to-format-dot-js/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664904/jquery-posting-form-via-ajax-not-triggering-rails-respond-to-format-js. No idea on the commented code as you haven't shown what changed in your question.

Comment: I hadn't seen those, thank you. As far as the commented code, I had removed the comments from my so question to clean it up, but hadn't removed it from the app itself. The controller action is now showing the request as js per the log, but request.xhr? is returning 0, not true. I can see the partial is called, but I am not seeing the success function get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Just add ".js" to the end of the url. Simple!