# Format.js in respond_to block doesn't work in an conditional format

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

I have this respond_to block which if a param is present, "format.js" will fire or else "format.html" will fire. My problem is this, the params will never be present initially, only until a user clicks on a link, which then fires an ajax response.

Here is the block:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if params[:tab_id].present?
    format.js
  else
    format.html
  end
end
```

I found this post: [JQuery posting form via AJAX not triggering rails respond_to format.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664904/jquery-posting-form-via-ajax-not-triggering-rails-respond-to-format-js) which seems to be a fix, but a reason I don't seem to understand why it works. With my problem, "format.html" will always be first when the page loads. How can I fix this so that "format.js" will fire when the user clicks on a link so that a params will be present?

Answer (score 0):

The format of the response is determined by the Accept header and the presence of a format (like .js or .html) on the request path.

`format.js` is only run if rails determines that the request is for JS. Rails defaults to `format.html`. Attempting to use a param for this is just not a good or even doable idea.

These are the MIME types [Rails recognize as js](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d4fb64b316f0f55468b17c58b50c384b04c5972b/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_types.rb#L8):

```
Mime::Type.register "text/javascript", :js, %w( application/javascript application/x-javascript )
```

To send an ajax request for js you thus need to do:

```
var promise = $.ajax('/somepath.js');
// or
var promise = $.ajax('/somepath', {
  dataType: "text/javascript" // or just "script"
});
```